# Interface Builder doesn't let me "SCROLL DOWN"

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios5, ios4

I have a UITabelView as my interface. My height is bigger than 460 pixels. I cannot edit any of my Table View Cells (or anything) below the bottom of the simulated APP at 460px I do not want to "programmatically add things in the interface." How do I "SCROLL" in interface builder??

I am using Xcode 4.2 and using STORYBOARDS as well!!

Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Set your view's y axis (-ve). Like if you have table view 600px which mean you have 160px non visible by default. For editing it make your view or table view to y axis = -160. You will get your view visible. But don't forget make it 0 again and height to 460 for running your app well.

I think this is what you was looking for. Let me know in case of else thing.